# render Multidimensional array react js

Tags: reactjs

how do display the array of the card in two columns instead of one with an image displaying sequentially?

```
return  (
    <div>
     
      {
        data?.length > 0 && data?.map(item=>{
          return(                
              <div className='home-container'>                    
                <div className='card-image-container'>
                  <img className='card-image'  alt="blank" src={item.photo} />
                </div>
                <div className='card-content'>               
                <h6 className='home-card-title'>{item.title} </h6>
                  <p className='home-card-desc'>{item.body}</p>                    
                </div>
              </div>
            
          )
        })
      }         
     </div>
  );
```

can someone tell me how to implement a multi-dimensional array in this?

Comment: can you give example how do you want it exactly with a demo array variable.

Comment: This sounds more like a css/styling question? do you want to map the data so that it outputs into 2 seperate columns?

Comment: @shaynel yes thats what i am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using grid in css

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```js
return  (
    <div id='grid-container'>
     
      {
        data?.length > 0 && data?.map(item=>{
          return(                
              <div className='home-container'>                    
                <div className='card-image-container'>
                  <img className='card-image'  alt="blank" src={item.photo} />
                </div>
                <div className='card-content'>               
                <h6 className='home-card-title'>{item.title} </h6>
                  <p className='home-card-desc'>{item.body}</p>                    
                </div>
              </div>
            
          )
        })
      }         
     </div>
  );
```

To add padding/styling to the grid, you can check out more options [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)